# Is it possible to identify 3rd party applications that use AD login?

Tags: authentication, active-directory

I am trying to figure out which third party applications are using AD login, or whether it is even possible to trace which applications are using the AD login? I spoke with an administrator at another company that said it was impossible to trace back which third party applications are using the active directory login, so I wanted to confirm this.

I attempted to find the answer on both Stack and Google, but was unable to find the answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The reason is simply that the application name isn't captured anywhere. The best you could possibly get is which computer a login happened on, which is still difficult to gather since it's in the event logs on each domain controller.